# Vue - how can i pass button value to submit in form?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a Vue form where there are two buttons. In my `formSubmit()` function i need to somehow find which button was used to submit the form. Here is what i tried:

```
<form @submit.prevent="formSubmit()">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="product">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" v-model="buttonType" value="button1">BUTTON1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" v-model="buttonType" value="button2">BUTTON2</button>
</form>
```

And my function:

```
formSubmit(){
  console.log(this.buttonType)
}
```

But once i click the button, i always get an `undefined`. Is there any other way to get the button used to submit the form? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really use `v-model` on a `<button>` element.

You can register separate event handlers for each button and call submit your form at the event of the respective event handlers.

```html
<form @submit.prevent="onFormSubmit">
  <button @click="onClickButton1">Button 1</button>
  <button @click="onClickButton2">Button 2</button>
</form>
```

```js
{
  // ...
  methods: {
    onFormSubmit() {},
    onClickButton1() {
      // code for when button 1 is pressed
      this.onFormSubmit()
    },
    onClickButton2() {
      // code for when button 2 is pressed
      this.onFormSubmit()
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: I think it worked, but there is a problem: it seems to trigger the formSubmit function two times, unless i'm doing something wrong

Comment: Try `<button @click.prevent="onClickButton1">...</button>`. Does this prevent the second form submission?